# Можно ли используя Entity Framework получить collation базы данных

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Если в Microsoft SQL server зайти в свойства базы данных, то во вкладке general 
 будет Collation. Есть ли возможность получить это свойство в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполните запрос к базе данных с указанием имени базы:

```
SELECT name, collation_name  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE name = N'BaseName';
```

UPD: Положить в переменную можно как-то так:

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter> {new SqlParameter("@DB_name", DB_name)};    
string query = "SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @DB_name;";    
string collation = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, parameters.ToArray()).Single();
```

Comment: Я не знаком с SQL вы не могли бы подсказать как значение которое я получу, запихнуть в переменую

Comment: и что означает name и collation_name?

Comment: @Maksims поле name означает имя базы, collation_name ее Collation, вам же достаточно получить ее Collation, способ я приложил.